# why php memcache connect function only takes 2 arguments

Tags: php, memcached

From resourses in Internet, the usage of php memcache is like that.

```
$memcache= new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

But I think of one query.
What if we put the first argument with host other than localhost?
Does it mean, when I know one's server IP, then I can access its memcache using this function?

It may be because I misunderstand memcache.

Hope someone can understand my query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcached is a daemon that listens particular port (11211 by default) and any number of clients may connect it from any machine (according to firewall rules, if any)

So, yes, if you install memcached to another server you may connect it remotely.

> Does it mean, when I know one's server IP, then I can access its memcache using this function?

Yes, if there is no any sort of firewalls on the target server and if memcached is set up to listen outer network interface - you could do that.

Comment: Is there a way to use authentication with memcache though? (I think that's what he is asking)

Comment: @Alex Lunix: I don't know any way to perform authentication. Memcached by design is very lightweight and fast, not sure it's worth adding authentication there. PS: yes, missed that in the original question, thank you

Comment: If someone has installed memcached in his own server, and I know his server's IP, that means I can access his server's memcache using the connect function?

Comment: @zerkms I believe he is worried about others connecting to his memcached daemon.

Comment: @user988988: if your memcached listens outer network interface and you have no firewall configured - then yes

Comment: if memcached is set up to listen outer network interface <---I don't quite understand this...

Comment: @user988988: `127.0.0.1` is a virtual network interface. It always refers to the local machine. It is accessible only locally. While `64.34.119.12` (ip of this site) for example could be another interface, that is accessible from outside. When any network daemon starts - it binds to one or many interfaces. And depends on that it is either accessible from outside or not.

Comment: How can memcached be set up to listen outer network interface?

Comment: @user988988: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer#Networking --- here is an official documentation that explains that

Comment: @user988988 this is the part where you mark his answer as right lol